# what does "humble" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> After 74-year wait, Brentford return to top flight in style by **humbling** Arsenal

Comment: Have you looked up _humble_ as a verb?

Comment: As a verb, it means to make someone understand that they are not as important or special as they thought.

Comment: Well - so obviously that is what Brentford did to Arsenal, presumably by beating them!

Comment: I think it means Brentford lower Arsenal. In the dictionary, "humble" also means lower someone in dignity

Comment: @Cocommentator - do you understand that both meanings are possible at the same time?

Comment: No, in that context it means lower

Comment: @Cocommentator - do you understand that if you make someone understand that they are not as important or special as they thought, then you also lower (verb, reduce) their dignity?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Co commentator. Please do a little research before asking a question, and include details of your research in your question. In this case, you could look up  **humble** as a verb in a good dictionary, like this one. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/humble

Comment: @Michael Harvey Yes

Answer (score 1):

> Arsenal suffered a humbling 2-0 defeat to newly-promoted Brentford on the opening

Kate's comment is correct.

Brentford have been out of the top division for 70 plus years, which makes them a bit of an underdog. Arsenal are one of the biggest names in football globally.

Brentford (the underdog) defeated Arsenal (the giants) which is a **humbling** blow. Arsenal are reminded that they are not unstoppable, even the underdogs are a threat, they should have taken this more seriously etc.

They are not as important or special as they thought, their self-opinion has been lowered. They have been **humbled**.